# Is it correct to say "What are your boys names?"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Is it correct to say "What are your boys names?" or "What are these fruits names?".

Comment: No, it is incorrect.  "What are your boys' names?" and "What are these fruits' names?" I can't find a suitable duplicate on ELL but here is one from the sister site ELU: [What is the correct possessive for nouns ending in "‑s"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1073/what-is-the-correct-possessive-for-nouns-ending-in-s)

Comment: You mean *correct*, not *true*: *true* and *correct* are similar but *true* means something like "matches reality", and *correct* means something like "matches a standard."  "I am ten meters tall" is grammatically *correct*, but is not *true*.

Comment: Note: Your use of "True" is incorrect.  "Grass is red" is correct grammar, but not true.  "Green, grass is" is odd grammar, but it is true.

Comment: Thank you guys I edited the subject. May you answer the primary question as well

Comment: Weather Vane has pointed out the necessary apostrophe.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian: Got it!

Comment: No-one will know the difference if you _say_ it, but it would be incorrect to _write_ it without the apostrophe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct statement is:

> **What are your boys' names?**

Fortunately, the [rules for possessives](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/what-happens-to-names-when-we-make-them-plural-or-possessive) are very straightforward.

If it were singular, it would be "what is your boy's name." There is an apostrophe-s to indicate possession (the name belongs to the boy).

The same rule applies for the plural form, but it just so happens that "boys" ends in an "s." So instead of adding an apostrophe-s, you simply add a lone apostrophe (boys'). You might pronounce this as "boys" or like "boyses."

The rule is not limited to plurals. It applies equally to something singular that ends in "s". For example, "Jesus' Teachings." You might pronounce it like "Jesus-es".

I intentionally try to avoid constructs like these because they are unnecessarily complex and I usually end up tripping over my own words.

Instead, I might say:

> What are the names of your boys?

or more simply:

> **What are their names**?

Answer (score 1):

As what everyone has said in the comments, you have to add an apostrophe to make it

> What are your boys' names?

and

> What are these fruits' names?

When we want to show that something belongs to somebody or something, we usually add an apostrophe + s ('s) to a singular noun and an apostrophe (') to a plural noun, for example:

> the boy's ball (one boy)

> the boys' ball (two or more boys)

In this case, you are mentioning multiple boys and multiple fruits, so you *have* to add an apostrophe.

Learn more about possessives [here](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/nouns-possessive.htm)